# Laravel 5.1 - Simple SQL Query gives errors

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

Trying to run a simple SQL query, but I keep getting the same error and I can't find a solution.

**The Query**

```
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $article_id = Request::input('articleId');
    $results = DB::select('select *
                          from favorites
                          where user_id = $user_id AND article_id = $article_id');
```

The variables `$user_id` and `$article_id` work, I tested that by `echo'ing` them.

**The error I'm getting**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$user_id' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from favorites where user_id = $user_id
>   AND article_id = $article_id)

**my favorites table**

[image: 1]

How can I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either use double qoutes:

```
"select *
from favorites
where user_id = $user_id AND article_id = $article_id"
```

or single with concatenation

```
'select *
from favorites
where user_id = '.$user_id.' AND article_id = '.$article_id ;
```

Comment: Or better yet, create a `Favourites` model and then use Eloquent